# Credentials are not remembered on a chrome extension popup

Tags: angularjs, forms, google-chrome-extension, credentials

For a chrome extension, I am using the popup (at the top righ of chrome) as a simple login form with Angular.
The popup is only one view displaying a login form or user info using ng-if and depending on the loggedIn state.

The problem is that only the username is saved and suggested by autocomplete on further login. Not the password.

See bellow the yellow username input after I selected `aaaa` from chrome's auto-suggested drop-down list. See also that the password is not automatically filed like it does on classic website form

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->

  <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-if="loggedIn">
    <p>
      <img src="images/logo-full.png">
    </p>
    <p class=""><strong>You're logged in as:</strong>
    </p>
    <p><i>{{user}}</i>
    </p>
    <br>
    <div class="center-block">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="logout()">Log out</button>
      <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-href="https://example.com/cockpit" target="_blank">Go to Cockpit</a>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="!loggedIn">
    <p>
      <img src="images/logo-full.png">
    </p>
    <form ng-submit="login(username, password)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="username" required placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" ng-model="password" required placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-if="error">{{error}}</div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="loading">Log in</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <a href="https://example.com/auth/reset" target="_blank"><small>Forgot your password?</small></a>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="margin-top-big">
      <a href="http://example.com/auth/signup" target="_blank" class="btn btn-block btn-success"><strong>Don't have an account? Get started</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <script src="lib/myLib.js"></script>

  <!-- build:js scripts/popup.js -->
  <script src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no integration between the password manager and extension popups, if that's what you're hoping to make work. Partly because it's impossible for Chrome to show the UI for proposing to save a password.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking, considering you didn't include any of your extension's code here.

Comment: @Xan You don't need other code than the html I gave. It's just a form for the top right popup of an extension. I added a screenshot for more information. But you are saying that it's clearly impossible to achieve that?

Comment: It's impossible for Chrome to prompt to save the password from a popup; I wonder if it would save if your form was opened in a tab, with `chrome-extension://youridhere/popup.html`.

Comment: Doesn't work neither when the popup is opened in a new tab